# regarding the filter in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

hi i have issue with the filter in wordpress.I have used this filter to set the  post type for the search.Its working fine but on search page in footer i am using plugin for post by categories and feature product.Filter is changing there query too.can you help  me to fix this so it apply to filter only no to the other plugin queries.
thanks.
here is my code

```
 add_action('pre_get_posts','search_filter');
    function search_filter($query) {

      if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query()) {
        if ($query->is_search) {
         $query->set('post_type','product');
            //echo "hello";
        }
      }
      return $query;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will search only in your custom post type `product` on frontend only.

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts', '_cpt_search');

function _cpt_search($query)
{
    if(is_search()) {
        $query->set('post_type', array('product'));
        return $query;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Learner you may need to add another condition in function to check what specific parameters are passing in search by plugin, try to figure out by `var_dump($query)` , i m pretty sure that plugin must uses its prefix or unique name to hook into search

Comment: @Nmman its woo commerce plugin to show product by categories and other on is show post by category both one using wp query